# is there a slackware linux netinstall?

Tags: linux, download, iso-image, slackware

Is there a netinstall for Slackware Linux? If so, where? I cannot seem to find one on their mirrors. Why not? Am I looking on the wrong mirror?

I need a netinstall because I'm making a netinstall DVD with the netinstalls for 10 different Linux distributions - and there isn't enough room.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Slackware USB boot image contains everything you need to do a network install. You can find it on the mirrors in slackware-current/usb-and-pxe-installers/ (you might want to read README_USB.TXT too).

If you're using something like memdisk to boot the ISO images, you might need to do a little more work to get the image into the right format, but that should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: [This blogpost](http://nixventure.blogspot.com/2015/08/slackware-net-install.html) advises not to use the main mirrors for a netinstall, because "*the main mirrors - slackware.org | slackware.org.uk - are throttled and may ban you, if you connect multiple times*".